# Not able to get the id of textarea which is closest to an image

Tags: jquery

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<img src="Image/icons/preview.png" alt="Preview" id="imgPreviewHeader" onclick="ViewHtml(this.id);" />
<textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHeader" class="editor"></textarea>`
```

And **JavaScript** code:

```
$("#" + imgPreviewHeader).closest('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet().execCommand('source');
```

Can anybody help me..?

Comment: what is id in this context

Comment: `closest` is the closest _upper_ element, you want `next`: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: what is `imgPreviewHeader` in this context? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) here because the textarea is the next sibling of the img element. [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will look for a match in the ancestor elements not in sibling elements

```
//assuming id has the value imgPreviewHeader
$("#" + id).next('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet().execCommand('source');
```

ie

```
$("#imgPreviewHeader").next('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet().execCommand('source');
```

Answer (score 0):

html..

```
<img src="deletered.png" alt="Preview" id="imgPreviewHeader" onclick="ViewHtml(window.jQuery(this).id);" />
```

javascript..

var texteditor= $("#imgPreviewHeader").next('textarea.editor').attr('id');
$('textarea.editor').val(texteditor);